# Postman Test script to set environment

Tags: javascript, postman

I need help with **Postman** test script, when i make an **API** call to **vRealize** Automation, i get the response Body value different form previous deployment. the data will be in different array, its randomly change.

here is what i have in the test script:

```
var data = JSON.parse(responseBody);

var Array1 = data.content
for(var i = 0; i < Array1.length; i++){
console.log("" + data.content[i].data.ip_address);
}
```

the console will prints:

```
undefined
192.168.245.211
undefined
```

the deployment after, the condole prints:

```
192.168.245.212
undefined
undefined
```

and the last deployment :

```
undefined
undefined
192.168.245.213
```

so the value located either on `data.content[0].data.ip_address`
    or `data.content[1].data.ip_address`
    or `data.content[2].data.ip_address`

what I'm trying to do is:

1) I want to ignore undefined value if I decide to print it to the console.
2) I want to replace `console.log` with `pm.environment.set` to set the ip address no matter where is the value located on array 0,1 0r 2

Answer (score 0):

You could use an `if` condition in the loop to check the items, if the item is not undefined, set that as the `environment` variable.

```
_.each(pm.response.json().content, (arrItem) {
    if(arrItem.data.ip_address !== undefined) {
        pm.environment.set("ip_address", arrItem.data.ip_address) 
    } 
}
```